# Binding keypress to contenteditable label

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

I want to bind a `keypress` event to a `contenteditable` `<label>`. This works as expected in Firefox, but in Chrome my bound function is not triggered by typing into the `<label>`. Note that this works for a `<div>` in both Chrome and Firefox.

[Pretty JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/Wk5LQ/1/), [raw JS JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/VBdDK/1/), relevant code below:

```
<label contenteditable>LABEL: This is some content in a label</label>
<div contenteditable id="div">DIV: This is some content in a div</div>

<div id="message">press key</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var eventDetails = function(event) {
            $('#message').html(event.type + ' event fired - ' + event.target.tagName); 
        };
        $('label, #div').bind('keypress', eventDetails);
        $('label, #div').bind('click', eventDetails);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a Chrome bug, and have [reported it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=keyup%20contenteditable%20label&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified&id=209871&thanks=209871&ts=1363554779).

Question is open to answers providing workable alternatives.